# Dictionaries with strings as keys and any values

Tags: dictionary, types, julia

I am trying to define a dictionary that takes strings as keys and any values. Thus, I try to use `Dict{String, <:Any}` as type. However, the return value to that expression is

```
> Dict{String,#s27} where #s27
```

Moreover, if I try to define a dictionary of that type I get an error:

- For `Dict{String,<:Any}()` I get `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Dict{String,#s28} where #s28()`
- For `Dict{String,<:Any}("aa"=>42)` I get `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Dict{String,#s29} where #s29(::Pair{String,Int64})`

I also tried using `Dict{String}` (which should be equivalent), with similar results.

What am I missing about types of dictionaries here?

Comment: “#s27” is a custom type correct? Maybe try it without the “#” in front.

Comment: @logankilpatrick No, or at least not created by me.

Comment: #s27 is a placeholder type name created by the parser with a weird name to avoid the autogenerated name to clash with another name. A human would probably just call it T for type, as in `Dict{String, T} where T`. That is another way of writing `Dict{String, T} where {T <: Any}`, which is the same as `Dict{String, <:Any}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `Dict{String, Any}`, not `Dict{String, <:Any}`. The first one is a concrete type, namely a dict that takes strings as keys and anything as values. The second, `Dict{String, <:Any}` is not actually a *concrete* type, but a *unionall* type. That means it is an infinite *set of types*. And the error you are seeing is that you can't instantiate this set of types. You can only instantiate a concrete (leaf) type.

Another way of writing `Dict{String, <:Any}` is `Dict{String, T} where T <: Any`, and that makes it a little clearer what it is. It is the set of all types of `Dict` that has `String` as they key type and a type that is a subtype of `Any` as their value type.

So for example we can say that `Dict{String, Int}` is a subtype of the infinite set `Dict{String, <:Any}`.

Edit: One use of unionall types is to be able to restrict the kind of type you take to fine grained level. For example, a counting function may look like this:

```
function count_stuff(stuff, counter::Dict{T, <:Integer}) where T
     # stuff here¨
end
```

The second argument here is a `Dict` that has some subtype of `Integer` as a value type and any type as a key type. That's basically what you'd need to use the dict as a counter.

Comment: To further clarify @Jakob Nissen's excellent explanation: When you specify a type as the type parameter of a `Dict`, that means it can store _any value that is a subtype of the specified type._ Of course, for a _concrete type_ like `String`, that's only Strings. But for an _abstract type_ like `Any`, that's _any value_.